# How to scan hidden folder such as ".nameFolder" in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to run SonarQube 4.5.4 on a project. Files and metrics are found for each folder except for the hidden ones (the ones like .m2, .something). Sadly those folders are the one that I am more interested in.

Is someone else experiencing the same problem? Are those folders filtered out by some default property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden folders are explicitly filtered out from the analysis. This is hardcoded in the SonarQube scanner. This is precisely to not spend time trying to analyze technical locations that are not part of source code (.git, .svn, ...). I think most IDEs are not showing hidden files, so this seem consistent.

Comment: Thank you, I've just found out the harcoded line! It worked out when I forced the files to be Sources, instead of inclusions. ;)

Comment: @julien-h-sonarsource-team Could you please link to the source of your otherwise useful information?